# Vertical arc using D3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js

How do I draw semi-circular arc along the y-axis ( perpendicular axis ) of an svg using D3 ?
Here is an image of what I want to achieve [target](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mfvrcmyunarns1s/target.png)

Here is my code so far :-

```
var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
           .attr("width",width)
               .attr("height",height);

var group = canvas.append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(0,200)");

var origin = d3.svg.arc()
           .outerRadius(50)
           .innerRadius(0)
           .startAngle(-1.5755)
           .endAngle(1.5755);

var arcs1 = group.append('g')
         .attr('class','arc')
         .attr("transform","translate(50,0)");

var yAxis = group.append("line")
             .attr("transform","translate(50,0)")
             .attr("x1", 0)
                     .attr("y1", -200)
                     .attr("x2", 0)
                     .attr("y2", height)
                     .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                     .attr("stroke", "black");
```

Comment: [This example](http://bl.ocks.org/cmdoptesc/6226150) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a d3 arc, an angle of 0 represents the top of a circle. So to make an arc like the one shown in your image, you will want your start angle to be 0 and your end angle to be halfway around a circle, which is Pi radians:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(50)
  .innerRadius(0)
  .startAngle(0)
  .endAngle(Math.PI);
```

As far as positioning your arc, you can use an svg transform to translate the origin of the arc to the position you want. For instance, if your y-axis has height `h` you can translate the origin to the center of the axis when you create the path element for your arc like this:

```
svg.append('path')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + h/2 + ')')
  .attr('d', arc);
```

[**HERE**](http://jsbin.com/hatuf/1/edit?js,output) is a demo.

Comment: :- how did u color the arc red ?? Can you please share the code ?

Comment: Check the CSS tab. I gave the path element a class of `arc`

Comment: :- thanks for the answer. Is there a way to marks points on the y-axis with values from my data-set ?? My data set is `var data = [[2010,15],[2010,30],[2011,45],[2011,20]]`. I need to mark data[i][0] to my axis

Comment: Sure, the first step would be to set up a scale for your data. Have a look at the documentation for the different types of scales [**HERE**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference#d3scale-scales). If you need additional help, we should either take it to chat or else open a new question so we don't get off topic.

Answer (score 1):

First, to draw the arc like your target you want your **startAngle** to start at **0** and **endAngle** to be **3.14** or **Math.PI**.

```
var origin = d3.svg.arc()
       .outerRadius(50)
       .innerRadius(0)
       .startAngle(0)
       .endAngle(Math.PI);
```

Then just append a path to arcs1 and use your origin function to draw it.

```
arcs1.append("path").attr("d", origin);
```

You can take a look at a live demo at http://jsfiddle.net/7EfS5/.

**Edit**
To change the color of your arc, you can either use **.attr("fill", color)** or **.style("fill", color)**

```
arcs1.append("path").attr("d", origin)
                    .attr("fill", "red");
```

Hope this help.

Comment: :- how do i fill color into the arc ?

Comment: Either `.attr('fill', 'red')` on the `path` element, or give it a class like `.attr('class', 'arc')` and then target the `.arc` class with your css and give it a fill property.